# SQL-Performing a query with two inner joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the below query with two inner joins, however it is returning no data... UtranCell is the PK and CELL_ID is the FK which I'm performing the join on however the below is returning nothing for me.

Would appreciate any help!

```
select 
c3.MeContext AS RNC,
c3.UtranCell,
c3.cId,
a3.azimut, 
d3.h_width, 
d3.v_width 
FROM E3G.UtranCell c3 
INNER JOIN 
(
select 
ct3.CELL_ID,
t3.TX_ID,
t3.azimut,
s3.NAME AS 'SITE_ID', 
s3.SITE_NAME, 
from ATL.UCell ct3, ATL.UTransmitter t3, ATL.Site s3 
WHERE ct3.TX_ID=t3.TX_ID AND t3.SITE_NAME=s3.NAME) a3 
on c3.UtranCell=a3.CELL_ID
INNER JOIN 
(
select 
ct3.CELL_ID,
t3.TX_ID,
t3.antenna_name,
ant1.physical_antenna,
ant1.h_width,
ant1.v_width 
from ATL.UCell ct3,ATL.UTransmitter t3, ATL.Antenna ant1 
WHERE ct3.TX_ID=t3.TX_ID AND ant1.physical_antenna=t3.antenna_name) d3 
on c3.UtranCell=d3.CELL_ID
```

Comment: You should add a sample of the data from the affected tables... Otherwise it's difficult to tell

Comment: mixing and matching old style joins with a failed explicit join. your c3, a3, and d3 simply do not intersect to a given row

Answer (score 0):

try to use the left join. and with this, you can understand which data the query doesn't retrive.

or you can try to execute,
the first query with 1 join, and try to understand which join not work how do you want.